# What is the minimal set of permissions for viewing connected instagram business account to a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two different facebook accounts (let's call them `B` and `E`) each with a page connected to different instagram account.

Going to `<page> -> Settings` in the UI, I can see the connected account details for both accounts. In both pages I have the editor role.

For account `B` (being editor for, `Page B`) having `page_show_list,instagram_basic` permissions I can make the `/v2.12/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account` request from the Graph explorer and it will return the id as expected.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "instagram_business_account": {
        "id": "1111111111111"
      },
      "name": "Page B",
      "category": "Arts & Entertainment",
      "id": "121212121212121212"
    }]}
```

For account `E` (being editor for `Page E`) having the same permissions doesn't throw error, but 
doesn't return the `instagram_business_account` either

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Page E",
      "category": "Arts & Entertainment",
      "id": "33333333333333"
    }]}
```

I am able to make it work for the second case only when I add `manage_pages` permission. With that included I get the correct data.

Apparently the `manage_pages` permission is not mandatory (works for page `E` without it) so I would like to avoid adding it to my app.

Am I missing any variables which could be different between the two accounts?

Comment: First of all, what are the actual user accounts you are using here? You write “page/account B”, as if the actual user profile managing the page, and the page itself, where the same thing ... but of course they aren’t.

Comment: Made edits to clarify this ambiguity. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Are you sure your user B had not granted manage_pages before already?

Comment: Yes and I observe this behavior with fresh access token from graph explorer (I explicilty revoke `manage_pages`) for user `B`

Comment: I think manage_pages is required for getting instagram accounts which are connected to Business manger. We are also facing the same problem. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @AshishPrakash that's exactly what the fb support told us when I filed a bug (I just forgot to update it here). We are now just going through the lengthy process of the app review for `manage_pages`, no other way around this, afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy is because `page E` was created with a business manager, while `page B` wasn't. We are now going through the lengthy process of app review to get the `manage_pages`.
Good luck to all!